# What's the best way to get a random(ish) sequence of printable/alphanumeric characters?

Tags: unix, shell, characters, random-number-generator

I know I can get random (well, pseudo-random) characters, unconstrained, from `'/dev/random'` (or `/dev/urandom`). But what if I need these characters to generate a filename? I need to somehow have a stream or a sequence of printable characters, or alphanumeric ones to be on the safe side. What's the best way to do that in the shell?

(I know I could theoretically do a `tr` on chars from `/dev/random` but that doesn't sound like the right thing to do.)

Comment: You may want to look at the `mktemp` command, unless for some reason you really only need to generate a name, without ever creating a file by that name.

Comment: @chepner: That's a great solution to my motivating problem, thanks! Unfortunately it's not what I ended up asking...

Comment: Convert the output of urandom to printable.  Or keep reading it and only output those in the printable range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tweaking of @dawud's [solution](https://superuser.com/a/584824/122798):

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=124 count=1 2>/dev/null | sha256sum | cut -c1-64
```

gets you 64 characters; and you can use `/dev/random` on UN*X systems without `/dev/urandom`.

A different, simpler approach, based on @NevinWilliam's suggestion: just do

```
date +%s.%N
```

No alphabet characters is a special case of alphanumeric... this doesn't cover the whole range of possible strings, and is limited to 9 characters, and it's not very random - except maybe the last 2-4 digits or so - but since we're not doing crypto, this should be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

I see `/usr/bin/jot` is capable of suppling a specified count of constrained random characters, which can be reshaped to a word suitable for a filename.  There's probably a more eloquent way of specifying all printable characters, but I'm a bit rusty on my shell scripting.

```
[mini-nevie:~] nevinwilliams% jot -r -c 25 A Z | rs -g
EUCGGSIOIDMPCHXCHIGYXBYWJ
[mini-nevie:~] nevinwilliams% jot -r -c 25 A Z | rs -g
PMKQQZOCYETVIHIMTIQFYTFZK
[mini-nevie:~] nevinwilliams% jot -r -c 25 A Z | rs -g
CXBKEFSIRCOOGUICJPOMZKMSG
[mini-nevie:~] nevinwilliams% jot -r -c 25 A Z | rs -g
MEHSFOSHLKKJRKQLRCXUCBJAD
[mini-nevie:~] nevinwilliams% jot -r -c 25 A Z | rs -g
ZCCGKYIWLBTJUVIHQBCHXCVEU
```

Comment: That's quite nice! ... of course, you need `jot` installed and I don't think it's installed by default (at least not on Debian systems).

Comment: It seems to be a BSD thing...  As you mentioned using the generated text (however you choose to generate it) for a filename, you might wish to tag on a sufficiently precise timestamp, such that as unlikely as it may be to fetch the same random string more than once, you'll still have a unique file name.

Answer (score 1):

`$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/stdout bs=124 count=1 2>/dev/null | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 1):

Using base64 on your urandom string will fix any encoding issue. You shoud try that :

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom bs=32 count=1 2>/dev/null |base64
A5o88RTh2LZlsr9F2r3jRPSqBZMMaa1EIAyndnVYhAQ=
```

change the bs parameter to get your expected length. You can also drop the last character as it is the base64 trailing character.